# How to generate an NSKeyedArchiver in PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

We have an app that receives from the server a file that was previously generated by an Objective C application using `NSKeyedArchiver`.

We now want to generate the same file using PHP. Is that possible?

Relevant Questions:

- What is the algorithm used by `NSKeyedArhiver`?
- Is there a function in PHP that mimics it?
- How can one in PHP turn a normal string into an NSData object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to decode an `NSKeyedArchiver` in PHP.

An `NSKeyedArchiver` is a binary plist of a specific structure, which this article describe: http://www.cclgroupltd.com/geek-post-nskeyedarchiver-files-what-are-they-and-how-can-i-use-them/

I used Christian Kruse's `CFPropertyList` (https://github.com/ckruse/CFPropertyList) to read from the binary plist. And using the article mentioned above I am able to look for the right key/object.

The `NSKeyedArchiver`s I am working with all have a simple structure in the first place (all of type dictionaries) so the serialised plist is relatively straightforward.

Following the same process but in reverse order is how I will take a named array, serialise it using the `NSKeyedArchiver`'s proprietary structure then turn it into a binary plist using the `CFPropertyList` library.

I hope this helps anyone.